# Elasticsearch: Get report of unmatched should elements in a bool query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for a way to get a report of unmatched should querys and display it.
For instance I have two user objects

User 1:

```
{
"username": "user1"
"docType": "user"
"level": "Professor"
"discipline": "Sciences"
"sub-discipline": "Mathematical"
}
```

User 2:

```
{
"username": "user1"
"docType": "user"
"level": "Professor"
"discipline": "Sciences"
"subDiscipline": "Physics"
}
```

When I do a bool query where the matching discipline is in must query and the sub-discipline is in the should query

```
bool:
  must: [{
    term: { "doc.docType": "user" }
  },{
    term: { "doc.level": "professor" }
  },{
    term: { "doc.discipline": "sciences" }
  }],
  should: [{
    term: { "subDiscipline": "physics" }
  }]
```

How can I get the unmatched elements in my result like that:

```
Result 1: user1 match 100%
Result 2: user2 match 70% (unmatch subdiscipine "physics")
```

I had a look into the explainApi but the result doesn't seems to be provided for that use case and seems very complicated to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [named queries](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html) for this.
Using the same , create a bool query like below -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "SourceName": {
              "query": "CNN",
              "_name": "sourceMatch"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "author": {
              "query": "qbox.io",
              "_name": "author"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In the result section , it will tell which all named queries matched.
You can use this information to fabricate the stats you are looking for.

Comment: Awesome! Many Thanks. Just got one more question, do you know if "_name" is reserved for "match" or can I use it "term" instead?

Comment: `_name` can be [used in all queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html)